# linq.js is modifying my source when I use Where()

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I'm using linq.js against a JSON array that I get passed from MVC.

It looks kind of like this..

```
[{ClAccountNumber : "101" Roles : {blahblahblah}},{ClAccountNumber : "102", Roles : {blahblahblah}}]
```

The problem I'm having is when I use the following..

```
   var val = Enumerable.From(clAccountsToRole)
                        .Where("$.ClAccountNumber = 101")
                        .Select("$.ClAccountNumber")
                        .ToArray();
```

My clAccountsToRole gets modified so that every row matches the 101 line.  So I get an array of 101, 101.

Has anyone used this library successfully or seen this issue before?

I should note that I'm using FireBug and before the call the array looks fine.  And if I remove the Where() part it works fine as well.  I'll get 101, 102 in an array.  It's only when I add the Where that things go wonky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you want a comparison operator?

```
.Where("$.ClAccountNumber == 101")
```

Comment: And here, the evils of EVAL are obviated.

Comment: Thanks!  Time to send in a bug report.. they should be warning on = usage in a Where..